# Angular array is not retaining its value after copying it to another and clearing it off

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating 2 arrays 1st has some value and 2nd is empty. After assigning items from 1st to 2nd array I am clearing 1st array, but it also clears the 2nd array as well.

My Code:

```
  array1: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  array2: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.array2 = this.array1;
    this.array1.length = 0;

    console.log('I cleared Array1');
    console.log(this.array1);

    console.log('Array2 Clears Automatically');
    console.log(this.array2);
  }
```

Here is Stackblitz sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yfhdi3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I don't want array2 to loose its value, as after assigning the value I want to do a loop on array2.

Answer (score 2):

Because array in javascript is an object, doing something like this `this.array2 = this.array1` means that both `this.array2` and `this.array1` are poining to the same object, so modifying any of this variables end up modifying the same object.  Use spread syntax to copy array elements from `array1` to `array2`, instead of referencing `array2` to `array1` like this ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9d7sn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):

```
this.array2 = [...this.array1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It will help for you.

 array1: any = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  array2: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.array2.push(this.array1);
    this.array1 =  [];

    console.log('I cleared Array1');
    console.log(this.array1);

    console.log('Array2 Clears Automatically');
    console.log(this.array2);
  }
```